# Count number of booking per day, using check-in and check-out dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compute (count) number of booking per day. My dataset contains check-in date, check-out date. Each row represents one booking.

I have the following codes to count number of booking per day:

```
df['duration'] = df['check-in date'] - df['check-out date']
df = df.groupby(['check-in date']).count()
```

My problem is that I don't know how to incorporate staying duration into my computation. Current, it only counts booking perday without considering staying duration.
If check-in date is 1/1/2020 and duration is 3 days, I want this booking to be counted in 1/1/2020, 2/1/2020, and 3/1/2020.

Answer (score 0):

No need to compute duration. Use `pd.date_range` to get a list of dates between `check-in-date` and `check-out-date` for each row. Then use `.explode` to create a new row of each element in the date list. Then use `.value_counts()` to get count of each date.

Code:

```
out = (df.apply
           (
              lambda x: pd.date_range(
                     x['check-in-date'],  x['check-out-date'], freq = 'd'), 
              axis = 1
            )
          .explode()
          .value_counts()
          .sort_index()
      )
```

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'check-in-date':['1/1/2020', '2/1/2020'],
                  'check-out-date': ['3/1/2020', '5/1/2020']})
>>> df
  check-in-date check-out-date
0    2020-01-01     2020-01-03
1    2020-01-02     2020-01-05
```

Output:

```
>>> out
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    2
2020-01-04    1
2020-01-05    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance our booking calendar like this:

```
in          out
1984-01-01  1984-01-04
1984-01-02  1984-01-04
1984-01-03  1984-01-05
1984-01-04  1984-01-05
```

firstly, we have to format string to datetime.

```
df['date_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df['in'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df['date_out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['out'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df=df.drop(['in','out'],axis=1)
```

output

```
date_in date_out
1984-01-01  1984-01-04
1984-01-02  1984-01-04
1984-01-03  1984-01-05
1984-01-04  1984-01-05
```

then we have to write all range of dates with **pd.date_range** except last day.

```
df['DATE'] = [pd.date_range(s, e, freq='d',closed='left') for s, e in
              zip(pd.to_datetime(df['date_in']), pd.to_datetime(df['date_out']))]
```

then explode and count

```
df.explode('DATE').groupby('DATE').size()
```

output

```
DATE
1984-01-01    1
1984-01-02    2
1984-01-03    3
1984-01-04    2
```